# centrpized spring secuirty for all APIs and users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am planning to use spring security for my platfrom as centralised .

I have my authentication server which does identification for Authorisation I want to spring security,

I want to have a centralised server for all Authorisation, centralised server will have all users, roles, APIs, action and context in data base.

Apigetway->Authorisation Server if Authorisation is correct then APi gateway->other micro service

But when I went to through the spring security it has only mvc method and preAuthorize method at each micro services, like below

mvc method.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Spring Security ignores URLs of static resources
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations());
    }


@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // configure login
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("account")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .permitAll();
        // configure logout
        http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
        // configure URL authorization
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/issues/").hasAuthority("readIssue")
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/issue/new").hasAuthority("writeIssue")
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/issues/").hasAuthority("writeIssue")
                .mvcMatchers("/users").hasAuthority("manageUser")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

PreAuthorize method

```
@GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("@securityService.hasPrivilege('READ_USERS') OR principal.username == #model.get('email')")
    public String getAccountView(ModelMap model) {
        return "user/account";
    }
```

Is there centralised way to handle spring security ?